# export to excel from sql server through query

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;
Database=D:\TestDB\First.xls;;HDR=YES', 
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT * from MasterData
```

And this error comes

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)"
>   returned message "Unspecified error". Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider
>   "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Please help

Comment: You need the appropriate OLE DB driver installed on the SQL server for this type of `OPENROWSET` query.  Take a look at this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130697/reading-ms-excel-file-from-sql-server-2005/24150349#24150349

Comment: yes i have try Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 but again server error comes

Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. Access denied.
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: That's a different error than the one from your original post.  The error in the comment above no longer indicates an OLE DB error.  I see `access denied`.  You'll have to do some more digging...Is the spreadsheet currently in use/opened by someone else?  What about the Windows login that is used to run the main SQL service?  Does that user have permission to open the file?

Comment: You may also want to check the file attributes of the spreadsheet.  Is it read-only?  If you open the file with Excel, is there any password protection?  etc.

Comment: No there is no password.

Comment: i have solve my problem with run as administrator thanks all

Comment: Check out this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720621/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-distributed-queries?rq=1